# How to select default entry at a dropdown menu for countries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I am using the `country-select` gem from [here](https://github.com/jamesds/country-select)

This is the form helper for the `country` field at the view:

```
<%= f.input :country, label: false ,input_html: { class: 'wborder answer-list-top', onchange: "enable_state()" }  %>
<script>
$("select[name='app[country]']").val('<%= @app.country %>');
</script>
```

I've seen that adding the `:selected => something` attribute is the way to do that but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Let's say, I need to add as the default country, `United States`.

*I'm really new to MVC and Ruby on Rails.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
<%=  f.country_select( "country", [ "United States" ],  :class => 'wborder answer-list-top') %>
```

Comment: How is this selecting United States as a default option? (Also, I cannot list all countries into the brackets, as I am using the gem file I've mentioned).

Comment: I have updated it. Now it will select United States as a default option.

Comment: This add an extra option of `United States` to the dropdown menu.

Comment: Yes it will show an extra option but it will be default option.

Comment: I need it to be one of the options available, not add one. This causes two options for `United States`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do with `select`

```
<%= f.select :country,{:selected => "United states"},{ class: 'wborder answer-list-top', onchange: "enable_state()" }  %>
```

For more details,see this [API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

**Edit**

`<%= f.select :country,Country.all,:id,:name,{:selected => "United states"},{ class: 'wborder answer-list-top', onchange: "enable_state()" }`  %>

This will give a list of countries in the dropdown with Unites States as selected.

Comment: Tried that, and got this error: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...=> "United States of America"}, input_html: { class: 'ra-bor...`

Comment: This displays a dropdown menu, with `selected` as the only option.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: undefined local variable or method `name' for #<#<Class:0x00000004d17870>:0x00000004c46310>. I think I managed to do that, without the `:selected` attribute, but by setting a default value to the country variable at the controller. But I don't know if that is a good practice.

Comment: @Chris Do you have a name attribute in your Country Model? If then it should work fine

Comment: @Chris Apologies.Forgot to add `:` to `name`.Updated.Please Check

Comment: Well, I get this error: `wrong number of arguments (6 for 2..4)`. Anyway, I'll keep the solution I told you, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `carmen-rails` gem.

```
gem 'carmen-rails', '~> 1.0.0'

country_select_tag("school[country]",(contact.blank? ? "US" : contact.country),:class=>'select_box required')
```

like that you can select the value.

More info [click](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails)

Comment: is my answer helpful?